# Non-Perfect maze generation with objectives

Tags: procedural-generation, python

I need an algorithm that can generate mazes with these requirements:

- Allows for random structures to be made (Ex: a center spawn area, objective points and 'Caverns (corridors with 2 or more entrances and a width > 1)' )
- Generates paths from structures to required connections
- Can be implemented in Python with relatively little difficulty
- No extra modules (unless supports Python 3.5.5)

As an example, the objectives would look like this in game (I use integers to store the walls in the ray caster):

---

> 2 2 2 2
>
> 2 0 0 2
>
> 2 0 0 2
>
> 2 2 2 2

---

I also tried looking on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Simple_algorithms)
and I found this semi-helpful [link](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm)
but none have helped me achieve this so far.

Comment: The phrasing of this question looks a bit like homework. While we're happy to help you in learning the material, we generally try to not simply hand out a complete solution to the assignment. Can you tell us a bit more about what you've tried so far, what's gone wrong, or where you're stuck, so we can help you overcome those specific obstacles?

Comment: so far, I am doing this as a personal project, and i am stuck with multiple maze generation, where the maze won't go around the obstacles I inserted. I am currently hand-making the maze for the ray caster i am making, but i would like to speed this process up with an algorithm.

Comment: Also related: [Algorithm for generating a 2d maze](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/910/algorithm-for-generating-a-2d-maze?rq=1).